# How to store radio button value in array and compare to correct answer?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I was using a jQuery plugins called "timer.To" to timed exam. Now what I want is when the timer hits 0, the radio buttons value will be stored on an array and then will compared to the correct answer w/c is save on an array too, count the number of correct answer and then submit it to the database and move to the next page..
Here is the code for the timer..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#countdown').timeTo(500, function() { // what should I do?  
      }); 
});
</script>
```

And this is for the form, it was created in PHP on an external file:

```
$Element = 0;
$countme = 0;
$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblquestions WHERE subject = '".$subject."' ORDER BY rand()");
echo '<form action="" method="POST" > ';
    echo '<fieldset style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius:7px; -moz-box-shadow:0 0 8px #666; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 8px #666; box-shadow:0 0 8px #666;">';
    echo '<table width ="100%" height="100%" style="border: 2px solid grey; " >';

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))
    {
               $Data [$Element] = $row['CorrectAns']; // ARRAY WHERE THE CORRECT ANSWER IS SAVE

        echo "<tr style='border: 2px solid grey;'>";
        echo "<td style='border: 2px solid grey; font-weight:bold; width:130px;'>Question # " .$countme."</td>";
        echo "<td colspan='3' style='border: 2px solid grey; font-weight:bold;'>".$row['Questions']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    $troll= 'QID'. $countme;  //USED FOR NAMING RADIO BUTTON..

        echo "<tr style='border: 2px solid grey;'>";
        echo "<td style='border: 2px solid grey;' ><label><input type='radio' name='".$troll."' value='".$row['choice4']."'>".$row['choice4']."</label></td>";
        echo "<td style='border: 2px solid grey;'><label><input type='radio' name='".$troll."' value='".$row['choice2']."'>".$row['choice2']."</label></td>";
        echo "<td style='border: 2px solid grey;'><label><input type='radio' name='".$troll."' value='".$row['choice3']."'>".$row['choice3']."</label></td>";
        echo "<td style='border: 2px solid grey;'><label><input type='radio' name='".$troll."' value='".$row['choice1']."'>".$row['choice1']."</label></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    $rawr[$countme]= $row['choice4']; 
    $countme=$countme+1;
    $Element++;

        }
$correct = implode('', $Data); // VAR CONTAINING THE ARRAY OF CORRECT ANSWER
    echo "</table>";
    echo '</fieldset>';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="art-button" value="NEXT --> " />
    echo '</form>';
```

The submit button is for submitting if the user finish before the time runs out. Please share your ideas with this, Thank You :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#countdown').timeTo(500, function() { // call this function here.

validate_answer();
      }); 
});


function validate_answer()
{
// take your $data variable and check for correct answer 
//passing your array through loop. and find marks and display it.
}
</script>
```

also call validate_answer() function on submit.

Comment: what does the function validate_answers() content?

    function validate_answer()
    {
     for(var i=0;i<=answer.lenght;;i++)
      {
         $Data[i] == ?? how do i get the radio buttons value?
//can you somehow show me how?

and also, how do i include a php array in javascript.. the last time i tried it.. it returns nothing in console.log..
      }
    }